Pairwise neutrality proof with Arrow's conditions
In the AGT book (page 213) they prove that if we assume $F$ is a social welfare function that satisfies unanimity and IIA we get pairwise neutrality, that is to say, let $\succ_1,...,\succ_n$ and  $\succ'_1,...,\succ'_n$ be two player profiles s.t. for all $i$ $a \succ_i b \iff c \succ'_i d$ then $a \succ b \iff c \succ' d$ where $\succ= F(\succ_1,...,\succ_n)$ and $\succ'=F(\succ'_1,...,\succ'_n)$.
The proof says that for all $i$ we should merge $\succ_i$ and $\succ'_i$ into a single preference $\succ_i$, by putting $c$ above $a$ and $d$ below $d$. This way we preserve the relation between $(a,b),(c,d)$. Now the book says that from unanimity we have that $c \succ a$ and $b \succ d$ and by transitivity $c \succ d$.
So my question is:

How does it derive from unanimity. How did we conclude that $\forall i,j$ we have $\succ_i=\succ_j$?
Here we changed our $\succ_i$ and got some result about the change in $\succ= F(\succ_1,...,\succ_n)$, but how does it tell us something about the original $\succ$?

